# Under which transformation of the Lorentz group do 4-momenta transform?

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, inertial-frames, group-theory, representation-theory

I am not quite sure about this one:

Do 4-momenta transform under the $1\oplus0$ representation of $SO(3)$ or under the $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ representation of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $4$-vector  forms an irreducible representation of the Lorentz group, since any Lorentz transformation mixes all four components. But from the point of the $SO(3)$ **subgroup** it is reducible since spatial rotations do not mix the temporal component $V^0$ with the spatial components $V^i$ of the $4$-vector.

Clearly the temporal component is invariant under a spatial rotation and so it's a singlet (which we indicate by its dimension $\mathbf{1}$) under $SO(3)$, while the spatial components form an irreducible three-dimensional rep of $SO(3)$ so they form a triplet $\mathbf{3}$. This gives the decomposition under $SO(3)$ that you give in your question $$\mathbf{4}=\mathbf{1}\oplus\mathbf{3}$$ which one can write also as $\mathbf{0}\oplus\mathbf{1}$, it's just another convention.

What we've seen up to here is the representation of a $4$-vector under a subgroup of the Lorentz group.

If we want to know in which irrep of the whole Lorentz group a vector belongs. For this we use the following isomorphism between the complexified algebras $$\mathfrak{so}(3,1)_\mathbb{C}\cong\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}\,\oplus\,\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$$ which physicists, somewhat wrongly, see as an isomorphism between groups. Using this isomorphism we can classify irreps of the Lorentz group using "two" irreps of the $SU(2)$ group. For this we use the convention $(m,n)$. $4$-vectors belong to the $\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ rep.

In fact in $SU(2)$ we have the following decomposition $$\mathbf{2}\otimes\mathbf{2} = \mathbf{1}\oplus\mathbf{3}$$ where the $\mathbf{2}$ is the fundamental rep of $SU(2)$ and so the rep of spin half. The relation between elements of the $\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ and complex vectors is easy to see.

Take the following generic element of the $\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ rep $$\left((\psi_L)_\alpha, (\xi_R)_\beta\right)$$ where $\psi_L,\xi_R$ are two independent Weyl spinors and $\alpha,\beta$ are spinor indices that take values $1,2$. Now you can easily see that this has four independent components, just like a $4$-vector. Moreover, if we define the matrices $$\sigma^\mu = (1,\sigma^i)\qquad\bar{\sigma}^\mu = (1,-\sigma^i)$$ where $\sigma^i$ are the Pauli matrices and $1$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, then $$\xi_R^\dagger\sigma^\mu\psi_R\qquad \xi_L^\dagger\bar{\sigma}^\mu\psi_L$$ are contravariant four vectors. Here we've used the fact that $$\xi_L = -i\sigma^2\xi_R^*\qquad \psi_R = i\sigma^2\psi_L^*$$ These four vectors are, by construction, complex. Since we want them to be real, we have to impose the reality condition $V_\mu = V_\mu^*$.

Therefore we have obtained the real four-vector representation.

**TL;DR:** Four vectors transform both as a $\mathbf{0}\oplus\mathbf{1}$ rep of the $SO(3)$ (spatial rotations) subgroup of the Lorentz group and as the $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ rep of the $SU(2)\times SU(2)\cong SO(1,3)$ group.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. To be honest I dont understand why you chose a combination of two Weyl spinors as an element of the vectorspace the representation acts on. This combination looks like a Dirac spinor to me, but they transform under ($\frac{1}{2},0) \oplus (0,\frac{1}{2})$ which isnt the same as $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, isnt it?

Comment: @maxxam No, the two reps are in fact different. You can simply see that since the vector one has two indices $\alpha,\beta$ while the Dirac one has only one. I encourage you to have a look at this really well done [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group)

Comment: I will read through the text in a minute. But because it looks like it is connected to another question I have and therefore I´d like to ask: I thought that $((\phi_L)_{\alpha}, (\xi_{R})_{\beta})$ is a $4\times1$ vector, but now it looks like it is a $2\times2$ matrix. Am I right or just stupid?

Comment: @maxxam That's correct. And it's not a stupid question!